# Redirect back with input not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a route post called "postContact" and when the post is success I redirect  to the same contact.blade.php where place the  post:

```
<form action="{{ route('post_contact) }}"></form>
```

I want to see a msg if the post have success, but the Input::get('some data') not working to me.

this is my controller resume:

```
public function postContact($params) {
 //if successful
 $msg_params = array(
      'msg_type' => 'success',
      'msg_text' => 'my text to show',
  );

  return redirect()->back()->withInput($msg_params);
}
```

But in the contact.blade.php this not working:

```
@if(isset($msg_type))
<div class="alert">{{ $msg_text }}</div>
@endif
```

The variables not exits...

**I don´t want use flash data here, because contact.blade is a module of another external app laravel and can't share sessions.**

What is happening here?

Comment: can you {{ dump($msg_params) }} on the contact.blade.php?

Comment: Rather than passing an array, pass each value separately by with like:

return Redirect::route('user')->with('msg_type', 'success')->with( 'msg_text', 'my text to show');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because doing a redirect, those variables are set in session. So you may try:

```
@if(Session::has('msg_type'))
<div class="alert">{{ Session::get('msg_text') }}</div>
@endif
```

If you don't want to use session variables, then you can use route parameters. You can get the parameters using the `Request` facade:

```
@if(Request::has('msg_type'))
<div class="alert">{{ Request::get('msg_text') }}</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Yes but I don´t want use flash data here, because contact.blade is a module of another external app laravel and can't share sessions. Have you another solution?

Comment: The only idea I have right now would be to send that message through the route.. being an external app you can't do it another way.. maybe that external app to have an api to let you set some variables before reaching it..

Comment: Do you mean to send url parameters?

Comment: Mmmm in the @if condition should I use 'input::get' ?

Comment: I think it would be Request::get

Comment: thanks, I accept yout answer, you should edit your answer with extra info about get my messages without session data

Answer (score 1):

If you're redirecting back to the page, Laravel will store the data in the Session. So you need to enter this to show the data:

```
@if(Session::has('msg_type'))
    <div class="alert">
        {{ Session::get('msg_text') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Yes but I don´t want use flash data here, because contact.blade is a module of another external app laravel and can't share sessions. Have you another solution?

Comment: Is it possible to set get variables in the url?

Comment: Like this? return Redirect::to(URL::previous().'&msg=success&msg_text=mymessage');

Comment: in this case as you get the parameters in the blade?

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', ['your message,here']);
```

Blade:

```
@if (\Session::has('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <ul>
        <li>{!! \Session::get('success') !!}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```